# How to compare the relative importance of features in GP regression?

Tags: regression, feature-selection, gaussian-process, importance

Kernel function with different length scales, such as the squared exponential function, is said to be able to quantify the relative importance among the input (predictor) features. The idea is to compare each length scale for each feature, and if the length scale is large, the corresponding feature's influence is negligible.

My question is then,
How to compare the importance of features with different numerical scales? like dolor, time, length, etc. Is there any way to standardize them?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is true, the length scale merely determines the idea of how close two data points are in a particular input dimension not how useful they are.

If you want to figure out an importance of each feature first look at your kernel and decompose it by removing the a dimension of x (ie remove a feature). Then determine the variance over you prediction space. Repeat for each dimension. How 'important' a feature is can be see as how much it reduces the variance on predictions.

Of course if your hyper parameters are such that you are over / under fitting the data then this is less useful and you can apply cross validation or leave one out (LOO) in order to gage feature importance.

Comment: It is not directly related, but I assume hyper parameters can tell something about the importance about the feature. If the hyper parameter of a certain feature is small, only a small change in that feature would cause very different output value. I assume if I take this input feature out from the input vector, the variance of the model would increase (or prediction accuracy decrease a lot).

Comment: The lengthscele is some what arbitrary though. For example if I use a feature of cents instead of dolars then the lengthscale would be 100 times larger but the feature is still equally important. You are right in saying for a fixed amount of input noise there will be less or more of an effect on predictions depending on the hyperparameters though. However you might expect in many cases the lengthscale an input noise may be in some way linked due to the under lying nature of the feature. What might be more interesting is the lengthscale versus the distribution over the input space.

Comment: Might be worth having a look at winsorization, which is typically what's used AFAIK in the Ax framework https://ax.dev/api/modelbridge.html#ax-modelbridge-winsorize. See also https://ax.dev/tutorials/visualizations.html and https://ax.dev/api/plot.html#feature-importances.